# Put user input in a pre formatted file and send this to an email address

Tags: ios, swift

I'm quite new to building apps and programming, but I got my first task to build an app that helps with the administration of my uncles company. The app has to take user input and put this into a pre formatted file, and send this file to his email address and the email address of the customer.

Do you have any ideas which structures I could use for this and how to convert the data into a pre formatted file, or even how to make this pre formatted file?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a very broad question:

In iOS you should not be creating a file and sending around through email. What you actually need to do is to allow user entering texts and then send them as html.

You can start by looking at [this](https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView) tutorial to allow user entering rich format text to a text view. Then you can convert that to html text and then send to email address [in this way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller).